# Problems with Location Manager

Tags: objective-c, location

I've been stuck on this problem for ages and I'm sure the reason is that I don't know enough about objective-c. I've only just started using coding with it!

Anyway I'm trying to design an app that tracks the current distance travelled and also displays the route that have been taken using MKPolyLine. I've got MKPolyLine sorted now but the problem I;m having is with getting the current distance. I think the code is OK but I think i'm doing something funny with location manager.

I've done a bit of debugging and found that my second locationManager method does not get called.

Here is the code below, if someone can take a quick look and just point me in the right direct it would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

.m :

```
@interface StartCycleViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *distanceManager;



@end

@implementation StartCycleViewController

static double totalDistanceBetween;
@synthesize cycleLocation = _cycleLocation;
@synthesize currentCycleLocation = _currentCycleLocation;
@synthesize mapView;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startCycleLocation];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    self.locations = [NSMutableArray array];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





#pragma mark - startCycleLocation

- (void)startCycleLocation{

    if (!_cycleLocation){
        _cycleLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _cycleLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        _cycleLocation.distanceFilter = 5;
        _cycleLocation.delegate = self;
        _startLocation = nil;

    }
    [_cycleLocation startUpdatingLocation];

}



- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    if ( [error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown ){
        [self stopLocationManager];
    }
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;

    [self.locations addObject:location];
    NSUInteger count = [self.locations count];

    if (count > 1) {
        // only both to add new location if distance has changed by more than 5 meters

        [self.locations addObject:location];
        count = [self.locations count];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            coordinates[i] = [(CLLocation *)self.locations[i] coordinate];
        }

        MKPolyline *oldPolyline = self.polyline;
        self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
        if (oldPolyline)
            [self.mapView removeOverlay:oldPolyline];



    }
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation2: %@", location);
}

- (void) stopLocationManager {
    [self.cycleLocation stopUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{

    NSLog(@"PolyLine Started");
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {

        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:overlay.boundingMapRect animated:YES];
        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
        NSLog(@"MKPolyline Rendering");
    }

    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)stopActivity:(id)sender {
    [self stopLocationManager];
    NSLog(@"Stopped");
}

-(void)distanceManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
      NSLog(@"Current Distance Started");
    if (self.startLocation == nil)
    {
        totalDistanceBetween = 0;
        _startLocation = newLocation;
    }
    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:_startLocation ];
    self.startLocation = newLocation;
    totalDistanceBetween += distanceBetween;
    NSString *cycleDistanceString = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithFormat:@"%f",
                                     totalDistanceBetween];
    _CurrentDistance.text = cycleDistanceString;
    NSLog(@"cycleDistance is %@", cycleDistanceString);

}


@end
```

.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface StartCycleViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocation *currentCycleLocation;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *cycleLocation;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocation *startLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *CurrentDistance;


- (IBAction)stopActivity:(id)sender;
@property(nonatomic, strong) MKPolyline *polyline;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *locations;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *currentSpeed;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *locationHistory;

- (void) stopLocationManager;



@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "second locationManager method", `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{`? Try putting a print statement at the very top. Do you get an error somewhere? Also try initialising `self.locations` before you start up the location manager so that you are sure it is defined when the delegate method is called.

Comment: Is `distanceManager:didUpdateLocation:fromLocation:` your "second locationManager method"?  1) Delegate methods must be named _exactly_ as defined in the protocol (you can change _internal_ parameter names but not the public part).  CLLocationManagerDelegate (see its doc) defines a `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method.  Your method name doesn't match.  2) Why do you even need two managers?  3) Location manager will call _either_ `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (iOS 5 or earlier) _or_ `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` (iOS 6 or later).  Not both.